# How to manage multiple activity interactions in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my activity, i'm calling activity B from activity A (in back stack A->B), than again activity C from B (in back stack A-> B-> C) for some result to reflect on activity A, than how to jump to activity A on button click with carrying some result from activity C to reflect back in activity A(while clearing back stack of  activity B,C)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**: You can chain calls of `startActivityForResult()` and "unwind" the chain in the `onActivityResult()` callbacks.

- Activity A calls `startActivityForResult()` to start Activity B
- Activity B calls `startActivityForResult()` to start Activity C
- Call `setResult(RESULT_OK)` and then `finish()` in Activity C
- Result of Activity C is received in `onActivityResult()` of Activity B. Process the result (if needed).
- Call `setResult(RESULT_OK)` and then `finish()` in Activity B
- Result of Activity B is received in `onActivityResult()` of Activity A. Process the result.

**Option 2**: Start Activity A again, but add flags to the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
// add more data to Intent
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This intent will be received in the `onNewIntent()` method of Activity A.

**EDIT**

**Option 3:** Use `LocalBroadcastManager` to send broadcasts locally (within your process only). This requires registering a `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically in Activity A, then sending the broadcast from Activity C. You will still need to use one of the two techniques above to get back to Activity A and clear the stack; this just changes how the data is transmitted back to Activity A.

Comment: Another options is to use EventBus (Otto http://square.github.io/otto/  or EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus ), this more more of a replacement for option #3.